# Fell into a seam (of seamless integration)?

Tags: support, new-users, login

Hi Meta-forum,

I wondered over to programmers.se today from SO for the first time, and posted a response to a users question.  I was a little surprised at being allowed to do this by just providing my name and email address, but once I saw my SE profile pic come up, I figured it must just be a common sign-on  (I'm using OpenID creds, via the verisign PIP site)

This was the question - and my response below [Do software engineers really need to know low level stuff anymore?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61936/do-software-engineers-really-need-to-know-low-level-stuff-anymore)

So, tonight I'm logging in from my home system.  As before, I first log into SO with my OpenID, and then navigate to here via the StackExchange navigator, and I find I'm not logged in.  I hit "Login" entered my OpenID, and it found and linked my accounts.

The problem is that my new account here doesn't have the question listed as posted by me - so it appears that is some other or "anonymous" account that just happens to have the same name and profile picture.

So - I'm mentioning this as it was a bit odd of an on-boarding experience that might be useful to consider for new user workflows.

I'd also be keen on getting that answer added to my real account, if there's an admin-type that I can appeal too!

Thanks - I'm very impressed with stackexchange site functionality and am glad to see it branching out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to explicitly log in to create an account on any site in our network.

**We don't automatically create accounts just for visiting, so just be sure to click that "log in" link first next time.**

On *subsequent* visits, once you *have created an account*, we can automatically log you in.

(anyway, I merged your accounts.)

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  That certainly seems like the right behavior.  I got fooled by seeing my gravatar next to my name when posting the first time into thinking that my account had been automagically created.